# Simple bash script to determine if a file is in a directory

Tags: bash, directory, arguments, compare

I'm trying to figure out in `bash` how to simply show that an argument which is a file is in another argument which is a directory, and then remove the file if it is.  I was thinking about setting a variable to `$(dirname $file)` and then comparing it to the directory name, but I'm not sure if that is the right direction to go in for this question. or would I do a `ls` of the directory and somehow match that to the file?

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `if` and `test` :-

```
file="somedir/somefile.txt"
if test -f $file
then
   echo "file exist"
fi
```

Example:- [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_(Unix)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_%28Unix%29)

Answer (score 1):

As stated, the question is slightly ambiguous.  It isn't entirely clear (to me) which file of the two should be deleted.  On further pondering, I think that if the file exists in the remote directory, the file name as specified should be deleted.  That leads to this script, I believe:

```
filename="$1"
dirname="$2"
basename=$(basename "$filename")
pathname="$dirname/$filename"
if [ -f "$pathname" ]
then rm -f "$filename"
fi
```

You could test for `"$dirname"` being a directory; however, if it is not a directory, then the pathname based on it won't be a file (so the test for it being a file will fail), so the test on the directory is superfluous unless you want informative error reporting.

Note that the script shown will work in the presence of blanks in the file or directory names.  Miss any of the quotes and it would not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the bash command `test`

You can use it by calling the command:

```
 test -f "$1"
```

`$1` is the first argument passed to the script, or you can use the shortcut:

```
 [ -f "$1" ]
```

A sample script to check if a file exists:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 [ -f "$1" ] && echo "$1 exists" || echo "$1 does not exist"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take care of **real location**, because you can treat **symlinks**.

So I recommend this solution (readlink look-up for the real path)

```
#!/bin/bash

file="$(readlink -f $1)"   # file is the first argument of teh script
dir="$(readlink -f $2)"    # dir is the secong argument of the script

[[ -e "$dir/$file" ]] && rm -f "$dir/$file" # shortcut to rm the file if the test case is true
```